# python datetime operation

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following error, can someone please explain the difference between datetime.datetime and datetime.date?

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.date'
```

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: sorry edited, python, i got the definition of both ojects from the docs but still struggling to understand the diff, is this only the seconds? how can i convert one of them to have the same format?

Comment: type `help(datetime.datetime)` and `help(datetime.date)`

Answer (score 2):

As the name implies, a `datetime` includes information about both the date and time, while a `date` is only a date. This is why subtracting two datetimes is allowed and returns a `timedelta` (the time difference between two instants), but subtracting a `datetime` and a `date` is not — since `date` refers to a whole day, it is unclear to what part of that day you want to calculate the distance to.

To fix the error, you must specify which point in the day your refers to. For example, to have it refer to the midnight at the beginning of the date, replace `dt - d` with `dt - datetime.datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day)`.

Answer (score 1):

`date` is just a date (year, month, day), while `datetime` also includes a time (year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, milliseconds).

You can't compare the two directly, because you need to explicitly specify how to deal with the time part. Do you ignore the time part completely, or do you select some arbitrary time to compare with when necessary (usually midnight)? This choice depends on which is the most appropriate to your situation, and really, only you can determine that.

In more concrete terms, you must either promote the `date` to a `datetime`, or demote the `datetime` to a `date`.  Given `dt` as the datetime, and `d` as the date, the latter is a little easier (and generally makes more sense - you can just call `dt.date()`), but the former is also not difficult (`datetime.datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day)`).

In your code, it would either look like `dt.date() - d` or `dt - datetime.datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day)`.

And note, that this will return a `datetime.timedelta` object, which is another slightly different animal - it doesn't represent a specific point in time, only the difference between two points (i.e, you couldn't use it as a date on a calendar).